# Python: Dictionary not passing out of my function

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a function that takes two dictionaries, adds them together.

```
from collections import Counter

def ReportTwoAddedDictionaries(DictOne,DictTwo):


    Dict1 = Counter(DictOne)
    Dict2 = Counter(DictTwo)
    DictTotal = Dict1 + Dict2

    print DictTotal

    DictTotal = dict(DictTotal)
    print DictTotal
    return DictTotal
```

When I run the function:

```
ReportTwoAddedDictionaries(FreePoints,FlyPoints)
```

it prints out DictTotal correctly (as it is told to do inside the function). However, when I try outside of the function, after running it, it prints empty

```
print DictTotal
```

Any idea why DictTotal is returning empty, but prints fine from within the function?
Thank you.

Comment: DictTotal is a local variable, unless you specifically calling it out as the global version of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the return value. A return statement doesn't just magically create a new variable in the caller's space.

```
DictTotal = ReportTwoAddedDictionaries(FreePoints,FlyPoints)
```

P.S. There's no need for the variable you use for the return value to be the same name as the one returned from the function.

```
foo = ReportTwoAddedDictionaries(FreePoints,FlyPoints)
print foo
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call this method:

```
ReportTwoAddedDictionaries(FreePoints,FlyPoints)
```

The returned value isn't stored anywhere. What you see being printed is the `print` inside the function.

When you call `print DictTotal` outside the function, it should throw an error, unless you've previously declared that variable.

If you store the returned variable in the current scope, like this:

```
DictTotal = ReportTwoAddedDictionaries(FreePoints,FlyPoints)
print DictTotal
```

You should see the dictionary printed as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can define DictTotal as global variable, which is visible outside the function scope, but its less recommended.

```
from collections import Counter

def ReportTwoAddedDictionaries(DictOne,DictTwo):

    global DictTotal
    Dict1 = Counter(DictOne)
    Dict2 = Counter(DictTwo)
    DictTotal = Dict1 + Dict2

    print DictTotal

    DictTotal = dict(DictTotal)
    print DictTotal
    return DictTotal

ReportTwoAddedDictionaries({1: 2},{'1' : '3'})

print DictTotal
```